# How to delete a cert mapping entry?

Tags: powershell, certificate, remote-access, winrm

I create a cert mapping entry with this command:

```
winrm create winrm/config/service/certmapping?Issuer=‎87d604dae22d91ee90f10a7dd91c33fc3093fd9b+Subject=PC01URI=* @{UserName="Administrator";Password="test123"}
```

But how can I delete this entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `winrm delete`:

```
winrm delete winrm/config/service/certmapping?Issuer=‎87d604dae22d91ee90f10a7dd91c33fc3093fd9b+Subject=PC01+URI=*
```